# Clickhouse modify TTL delete all rows from ReplacingMergeeTree table

Tags: sql, clickhouse, ttl

I need to change TTL in ReplacingMergeTree from 34 days to only 3 days, but when i changed TTL, all rows are deleted.
I have ReplacingMergeTree table created with this query:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
    `timestamp` DateTime('UTC'),
    `version` DateTime('UTC'),
    `hid` UInt64,
    `port` UInt32,
    `rps` Float32,
    `bps` Float32
)
ENGINE = ReplacingMergeTree(version)
PARTITION BY toYYYYMMDD(timestamp)
ORDER BY (timestamp, hid, port)
TTL timestamp + toIntervalDay(34)
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192;
```

Then i've inserted some rows with timestamp from 16 april to 24 april. And `select * from test` returns this lines:

| timestamp | version | hid | port | rps | bps |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-16T06:00Z | 2023-04-24T16:03:32Z | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2022-04-17T06:00Z | 2023-04-24T16:03:32Z | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

...

| timestamp | version | hid | port | rps | bps |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-24T06:00Z | 2023-04-24T16:03:28Z | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

If i check partitions from system.parts with `select table, partition from system.parts where table = 'test'`, in result i can see all of partitions, 9 partitions from `20220416` to `20220424`.
Next i remove TTL with query `alter table test remove ttl` (this step is optional and i'm tried without this step, anyway result be same) and set new ttl with `alter table test modify ttl timestamp + toIntervalDay(3)`, and next all rows from table is disappear and `select * from test` return 0 rows.
Why is this happening and what am I doing wrong?
Optimize/final don't fix problem.

Comment: `2022-04` - 2022 - a year ago. It's expected  for TTL `timestamp +3 days`

Comment: Oh my god, really‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was that I wrote 2022 instead of 2023‍♂️